# What is the purpose of the archetypeArtifactId?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

When create a new project, it requires to set the `archetypeArtifactId`. Anyone know the meaning of this element?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you mean creating a new POM or a new project? For a new project when you provide the `archetypeArtifactId` you are informing maven what archetype to use to create the initial structure of the project. Maven looks it up from the [`archetypeCatalog`](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html#archetypeCatalog).

For example, if you want to create a simple web-app project you specify [`-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-webapp.html).

**UPDATE**
I found this [list](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/index.html) for a compilation of some of the commonly used archetypes.

Comment: where to get all the archetypeArtifactId?

Comment: @user496949: I added a link above but it does not cover all for sure. You can always add `-DarchetypeCatalog` to point the location of the catalog.

Comment: The link to the list is not available anymore, here is an updated one: http://myjeeva.com/exclusive-maven-archetype-list.html 
I edited the post to add it.